# Mysql creating table error integer

Tags: mysql, int

With this code:

```
create table jogadores(
id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome varchar NOT NULL,
idade int NOT NULL UNSIGNED,
nacionalidade varchar NOT NULL
)
```

I keep getting this error:
)
Error report -
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
idade int NOT NULL UNSIGNED,
nacionalidade varchar NOT NULL
)' at line 3.

Also, I get the red underline under the "T" and the "(" in "INT(10)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`varchar()` should have a length:

```
create table jogadores (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    idade int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    nacionalidade varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

And `UNSIGNED` needs to go immediately after the numeric declaration, not after `NOT NULL`.  See [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6de33).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the length of the varchar i.e. `varchar(100)`.